# Arguments in a Microsoft Service

Tags: c#, service

I'm trying to make a tool that will launch an application on another PC through a combination of batch files and a custom service.

At the moment, my program only runs one specific program on the hit of a button. When I hit the button (held in a winform) it begins a batch files that runs my exe found on my target PC. Like so:

```
    // when the service starts open paint
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {


        // name of the application to launch
        String applicationName = "C:\\TargetFolder\\Target.exe";

        // launch the application
        ApplicationLoader.PROCESS_INFORMATION procInfo;
        ApplicationLoader.StartProcessAndBypassUAC(applicationName, out procInfo);
    }
```

Then when I hit the close button, this happens

```
   // when the service is stopped close the client
    protected override void OnStop()
    {


        // name of the application to launch
        String batchFile = "C:\\BatchFiles\\KillClient.bat";


        // launch the application
        ApplicationLoader.PROCESS_INFORMATION procInfo;
        ApplicationLoader.StartProcessAndBypassUAC(batchFile, out procInfo);
    }
```

My winform runs this batch file:

```
@echo off
net start "MyNewService"
```

Now though, I am trying to make my original tool open up specific exes depending on the button, without the need to make X amount more services. Who's sole job would be to run this single exe.

For example, if I want one button to up paint, another to close it down, another to open up word and a final one to close that. How would I do so in a service?

Comment: Sounds like a job for PowerShell remoting...

Comment: I think you need to be clearer in your own mind what the requirement is - why do you want to use batch files ? Why do you want to use a service ?  Why cant you just use RDP ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't use a service for a program that has a UI and requires user interaction.

A service is meant for a program that runs quietly in the background without any human intervention (other than starting and stopping it perhaps).

If you want human interaction a regular Windows Application (WinForms, WPF,...) is what you need to write.

Comment: It's over a network. All my interaction does it simply run this service. The user isn't directly using it in the slightest. All my UI does it turn it on or off.

I'm just wondering if I can make my service turn specific exe's on and off with the press of a button.

Comment: @N0xus - A service doesn't have a UI. Whether it's over a network or not is irrelevant.

Comment: I get that, but a service can still be turned on and off through the control panel. My tool, removes having to go into the control panel to start and stop this process.

My service has no direct UI. I have made a winform that will simply turn this process on or off without the need to go into the control panel.

Comment: @Noxus - Chris's comment perhaps will come home to you if you ask yourself what will happen if the service is running and there is no user logged on ...

Comment: aaah - are you saying you want to remotely start and stop a service ? Your question sounded like you wanted the service to start and stop programs.

Comment: @N0xus - No you haven't. You've replaced something that runs regardless of which user is logged in, or indeed whether any user is logged in, with something that only runs when the current user is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to carefully consider the answer given by Chris above because there has been a lot of effort in recent years to tighten security in Windows Operating Systems.  One change which came in with Vista (I call that recent :)) was that services now run as 'User0', not 'User1' as previously.  User0 does not have access to the screen.

What you are trying to do is bypass the security.  I said above - consider what would happen when no user is logged onto the target machine, but you also might consider what you want to happen if MANY users have active sessions.  It seems to me you need to backtrack a little and formulate the requirement more closely.

That having been said, your question title asks how to pass parameters to a Windows Service.  2 answers spring to mind -

1. you could perhaps implement the service as a WCF service.(Not a Windows Service)  This would allow you to define a method that receives the arguments you want to pass.  WCF also has the flexibility of being hostable in a number of different ways.  Consequently this might resolve some of the issues Chris and I have raised; a console host that runs when a particular user logs in might make more sense for your particular problem.  You could also host your WCF service in a Windows service - I mention this with all the reservations expressed above.
2. You could implement a Windows(NT) service that opens a listening socket.  Your launcher app connects and passes parameters through a socket conversation.

Doubtless there are other ways.